# Facing issues with validations in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I want to add validations to a form which is used to change the date of an event. And if a user forgets to pick the new date, I want to notify that they should select a new date.

In my model I have used data annotations for that specific attribute as follows:

```
    [Required]
    public DateTime Estimated_Start_Date { get; set; }
```

This is the controller for changing date

```
public ActionResult Change(int? Id)
    {
        var dtl = _context.pm_main_repz.Include(a => a.PM_Evt_Cat).SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == Id);
        if (dtl == null)
        {
            return Content("No item found!");
        }
        var vm = new PM_InsertEdit_ViewModel()
        {
            pm_main_rep = dtl,


        };

        return View(vm);
    }
```

This is the view for changing Date

```
 @model Project.ViewModel.PM_InsertEdit_ViewModel

 @using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeDate", "PM", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
 {


<div class="form-group">
    <label>Select New Date</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.pm_main_rep.Estimated_Start_Date, new { @class = "form-control"})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a=> a.pm_main_rep.Estimated_Start_Date)
</div>

@Html.AntiForgeryToken();
@Html.HiddenFor(a => a.pm_main_rep.Id);
<button class="btn btn-primary">Request</button>
}
```

Now this is the ChangeDate Method within my controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ChangeDate(PM_InsertEdit_ViewModel ap)
    {

        var item = _context.pm_main_repz.Single(a => a.Id == ap.pm_main_rep.Id);
        item.Estimated_Start_Date = ap.pm_main_rep.Estimated_Start_Date;

        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Success", "PM");
    }
```

Please note that till this moment everything works fine if I don't enforce validation by checking the ModelState, but if I do so, it does not recognize a portion of code and underlines it with RED color.

This is the code when I want to check the ModelState within ChangeDate Method. Basically I want that the users should remain in the same view unless they select a new date.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ChangeDate(PM_InsertEdit_ViewModel ap)
    {

  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var dtl = _context.pm_main_repz.Include(a => a.PM_Evt_Cat).SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == Id);   // Note: It underlines the Id with red and says: The Name Id does not exist in the current context
            var vm = new PM_InsertEdit_ViewModel()
            {
                pm_main_rep = dtl,
            };
            return View("Change",vm);
        }

        var item = _context.pm_main_repz.Single(a => a.Id == ap.pm_main_rep.Id);
        item.Estimated_Start_Date = ap.pm_main_rep.Estimated_Start_Date;

        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Success", "PM");
    }
```

The Error is as follows:

> The Name Id does not exist in the current context,

Even though I'm close to solve this issue, but I am puzzled somewhere in logic.

Comment: In this line: `SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == Id)` , what is the second Id supposed to be?

Comment: @TanvirArjel This line,  var dtl = _context.pm_main_repz.Include(a => a.PM_Evt_Cat).SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == Id);

Comment: @TanvirArjel Write an answer, that will help the OP too and it will help future readers. And the spirit of a QA site like this is to have answered questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ModelState.IsValid only validates using the default model binder which in your code is PM_InsertEdit_ViewModel. That is not part of the compiler error you are getting. You can try to remove that line then just return back ap parameter to the view like so: return View("Change", ap);

With this when IsValid is not valid you return the data the Action have received so that the user can edit his/her input.

Comment: my pleasure @JohnKamaal

Comment: Hello, this is a similar issue, kindly give it a look when you get time.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55088268/after-implementing-validations-in-c-i-face-problems-in-updating-records    thanks in advance