# After Implementing Validations in c#, I face problems in updating records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm working on a project in Asp.net c# MVC and I want to implement validations on a model using Data Annotations as follows:

```
public class MainRepository
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public int Category_Id { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public int Department_Id { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public DateTime Start_Date { get; set; }
}
```

I have a controller as PM controller with the following Register Method.

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
       var event_category = _context.Event_Categories.ToList();
       var departments = _context.dept.ToList();
       var vm = new InsertEdit_ViewModel
       {
           evt_catgrss = event_category,
           depts = departmetns 
       };
       return View(vm);
   }
```

Here is the InsertEdit view Model:

```
public class InsertEdit_ViewModel
{
    public MainRepository Main_RP { get; set; }
    public List<Event_Categories> evt_catgrss { get; set; } 
    public List<Departments> depts { get; set; }
}
    public InsertEdit_ViewModel()
    {
        Main_RP = new MainRepository();
        evt_catgrss = new List<Event_Categories>();
        depts = new List<Departments>();
    }
}
```

And this is the view for the Register Method:

```
@model Project.ViewModel.InsertEdit_ViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Store", "PM", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Event Category</label><br/>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.Main_RP.Category_Id, new SelectList(Model.evt_catgrss, "Id", "type_of_event"), "Select a category", new { @class = "form-control btn-group dropdown-menu" })

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a=> a.Main_RP.Category_Id)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Department</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.Main_RP.Department_Id, new SelectList(Model.depts, "Id", "DepartmentName"), "Select Employee Department", new { @class = "form-control btn-group dropdown-menu" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a=> a.Main_RP.Department_Id)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Start Date</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Main_RP.Start_Date, "Select Estimated Date of Start", new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly", @style = "cursor :default; background-color:#d4d4d4; font-size:11px;" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a=> a.Main_RP.Start_Date)
</div>


@Html.AntiForgeryToken();
<button class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>

}
```

And finally this is the Store Method within the PM controller

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public ActionResult Store(InsertEdit_ViewModel pmI)
 {
       if (!ModelState.IsValid)
       {

       var event_category = _context.Event_Categories.ToList();
       var departments = _context.dept.ToList();
       var vm = new InsertEdit_ViewModel
       {
           evt_catgrss = event_category,
           depts = departmetns 
       };


        return View("Register",vm);
        }
        _context.main_repz.Add(pmI.Main_RP);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "SystemAdmin");
   }
```

Now till this portion everything is working fine including the validations. But I'm facing issues whenever i want to change the date of an event with another method as follows:

This is the Change Method within PM Controller:

```
public ActionResult Change(int? Id)
  {
      var EventDetails = _context.main_repz.Include(a => a.Event_Categories).SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == Id);

      var vm = new ChangeVM()
      {
          Main_RP = EventDetails

      };

      return View(vm);
  }
```

This is the ChangeVM (ViewModel)

```
public class ChangeVM
{
  public MainRepository Main_RP { get; set; }
  public ChangeVM()
  {
     Main_RP = new MainRepository();
  }
}
```

This is the view for Change Method

```
@model FEFA_MIS.ViewModel.ChangeVM


@using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeDate", "PM", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{


<div class="form-group">
    <label>Select New Date</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Main_RP.Start_Date, "{0:}", new { @class = "form-control"})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a=> a.Main_RP.Start_Date)
</div>
@Html.AntiForgeryToken();
@Html.HiddenFor(a => a.Main_RP.Id);
<button class="btn btn-primary">Request</button>
}
```

And Finally this is the ChangeDate Method within PM controller

```
   [HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public ActionResult ChangeDate(ChangeVM ap)
   {
       if (!ModelState.IsValid)
       {


           return View("Change",ap);
       }


       var item = _context.main_repz.Single(a => a.Id == ap.Main_RP.Id);
       item.Start_Date = ap.Main_RP.Start_Date;
       _context.SaveChanges();
       return RedirectToAction("Success", "PM");
   }
```

Now this time it is not working properly,

Means, If I don’t select the new date It gives the validation message, which is perfectly fine.

But when I select the new date It does not proceed as I think it is expecting the Category_Id and Department_Id too, but they are no longer part of ChangeDate Method, they were part of Store Method used for Registration.

If i'm not mistaken, I think all of the three [Required] fields in the model, come under one ModelState, but anyhow I'm stuck here...

what can be the solution? Can the View Models access only specific attributes instead of calling the whole class (as in my case)?

Comment: @haim770 as you can see in my code, there are two different view models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use the MainRepository in your ChangeVM. This includes all properties. Instead, limit your ViewModels to only those fields, that you are actually processing in that view. So, just add Id and Start_Date to the ChangeVM, and you should be good.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I thought about this solution too but don't know how to access those two specific fields within the ChangeVM, I forgot the syntax, could you please help??

Comment: Just like your MainRepository:
`public class ChangeVM { public int Id { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public DateTime Start_Date { get; set; }
}`

Comment: Although, you will most likely want the `[Required]` attribute also on the `Id` property.

Comment: Why are you using [Required] in ChangeVM as it is already defined in Model, shall i use it at both places? or shall i remove it from Model and use it in ViewModel, the way you did in ChangeVM ?

Comment: Since you are removing the MainRP from the ChangeVM, you will also no longer have access to its `Id` property. That's why it must be in the ChangeVM directly.

Comment: ok, but i didnt understand one thing.. how Id and Start_Date fields in the ChangeVM are connected with the Id and Start_Date fields of MainRepository ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189770/discussion-between-john-kamaal-and-christoph-herold).

Answer (score 0):

When you try to do  update operation you must provide required properties value.This is mandatory.
Thanks